# how to get pdf files uri taht is stored in assets folder and am getting InputStream from assetmanager. so how to get pdf uri from that inputstream?

Tags: android, file

returning **inputstream**. so how can I get my pdf files URI?

```
assetmanager.open("filename.pdf")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the pdf uri from inputstream.
to get that, you need to write a file from InputStream, and then you can get a uri from the file.
#1: To write a file from InputStream
#2: To get a uri from the file

Comment: please tell me how to make a "pdf" file from inputstream sir.